# How do i remove error warnings made by tpl files in my eclipse project

Tags: php, eclipse

Recently i installed eclipse 3.5.2 with php support and when i created my php project all tpl files appeared with errors, seem to be searching zend_debugger, how do i remove that errors for the sake of keep my code flow normal with no red warns everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the errors in the Problem views, and press Delete (or Right click/Delete).

This won't prevent Eclipse of recreating the errors, but if they were just not disposed correctly, this will help.