# How to exclude files/folder from Markers view in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, markers

Is there a way in eclipse to stop markers from showing in the Markers view for files in a certain folder? I.e. I imported a Javascript library that I didn't write myself but it is going to be part of my project and I don't want to have to look at all the "TODO" and "FIXME" markers in those files and would just want to see my markers only... Is there a way to exclude certain folders or files form being scanned by the markers process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, I was able to resolve this by adding the folders I wanted to exclude to the exclusion list under Project->Properties->Validation. (Click settings beside each validation, Add Exclude Group button, Add Rule button, select folder option, browse for relative folder)

Comment: +1 Which validators need to be configured varies based on the project and language. For example, `PHPTaskValidator` is what you would configure for PHP tasks.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the content of the Markers view (the one displaying errors and warning in source code) and the content of the Tasks view (the one displaying "TODO" and "FIXME") by clicking on the **"small down arrow" in the top right of the view** (near the minimize and maximize buttons) and then clicking on **Configure Contents ...** entry.

Hope this can help,
Manu

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already know about the Configure Contents feature but it doesn't allow me to exclude certain folders within my working-set which is what my question is specifically about.

Answer (score 3):

By selecting **Configure Contents** like Manu said, there is also the option to list the tasks for a specific **working set**, using the **Scope** area at the right.

That worked for me, and I'm not annoyed anymore by all Zend Framework @todo.

Hope this helped, Stéphane

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing a node app and wanted to exclude my node modules folder. I found the only way to do this is to create a working set that excludes that directory and set the Task -> configure contents to that working set.

[How to exclude a folder that is producing warnings/errors in an Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736208/how-to-exclude-a-folder-that-is-producing-warnings-errors-in-an-eclipse-project)