# Eclipse Zend PDT hide todo/tasks/warnings from zend-framework

Tags: eclipse, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt

Is it possible to hide the todo's/tasks/warnings from specific folders in eclipse? E.g. I'm using the Zend framework in one of my projects with the zend mvc folder structure. So zf is in the folder library. Having several hundrest todos from the Zend library within my project is kind of distracting.

Comment: I am not sure about Eclipse but, if you plan to use NetBeans, there is an option in their filters.

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594945/how-to-exclude-files-folder-from-markers-view-in-eclipse

Comment: I also found this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783902/excluding-disabling-validation-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
May be this will work for you.

Right click project
Select properties
Select validation
Check Enable Project specific settings
On the XML Validator row, click the '...' button
Select Exclude Group
Click Add rule
Select 'Folder or file name'
Click Next
Select files or folder which are not validated.
Click Finish
Click OK
Click OK
```