# error on every external java script file in nodeclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, backbone.js, nodeclipse

Nodeclipse gives an error on external .js when copied, but works fine project run, how to remove those error , or is there a another way to include those external .js file in node project, if then how to do that [image]

here is screen shot of it.

any help is appreciated. tu

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my project works well, i think there no error in those .js file,in nodeeclipse it shoes red marks

Comment: _"a specific problem or error"_: What are the errors eclipse is throwing?

Comment: this error are inside .js lib files, Multiple markers at this line
 - Expected '{' and instead saw 
  'data'

Comment: Hm, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736208/how-to-exclude-a-folder-that-is-producing-warnings-errors-in-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 0):

The question is why there are red error markers.

That is standard for Eclipse.

Reset Node perspective to get Problems View, and see what Eclipse says about all those errors.