# Eclipse CDT - Ignore directories for Code Analysis

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The project that I am working on has a large number of external dependencies (library headers, for example) inside.

When I try to run code analysis, these files generate a huge number of warnings.

How can I configure the Code Analysis tool to ignore these directories when running its analysis?

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse Project Explorer, right click a folder you want to hide and select properties.  For example 'vendor' or 'lib'.

Select Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filter

Click 'Add'

Filter Type: 'Exclude All'

Applies To: 'Files and Folders'

Filter Details: Name -> matches -> '*'

Make sure 'Regular expression' is checked.

Now rebuild your index.  Right click your project -> Index -> Rebuild

Comment: The problem with that is then that the C++ parser can't find these headers, and so you end up with a bunch of unknown type and unknown method errors.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct.  Perhaps there is a solution here for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736208/how-to-exclude-a-folder-that-is-producing-warnings-errors-in-an-eclipse-project