# Eclipse errors in CakePHP 3.x vendor folder

Tags: eclipse, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3.x vendor folder Eclipse highlites a lot of lines with potential errors (even though in my opinion there are none), e.g.

```
namespace <%= $namespace %>\Controller<%= $prefix %>;
```

The example error message is as follows:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line
- syntax error unexpected "%="
- syntax error unexpected "<"
```

How can I turn off the errors? I already turned on "Use Short Tags" in Properties/Interpreter (didn't help).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude a folder that is producing warnings/errors in an Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736208/how-to-exclude-a-folder-that-is-producing-warnings-errors-in-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate - that's talking about Java source folders, not validation errors

Comment: I don't consider it as duplication either.

Comment: don't know in eclipse, but in NetBeans you have to check 'enable ASP tags' in the project options

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/php_interpreter.htm)

Comment: I checked that button already - however it is called "Use Short Tags" in my Eclipse

Comment: @AlBlue and OP, sorry, I've pasted the wrong URL, I ment to link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse**

Comment: The resource filters are for ignoring the resources completely though, which may not be what's required here.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that will not be a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn off the validation for the file, by going to Preferences -> Validation and then unselecting the options that are using the XML validation (which won't understand tags like <%)

Comment: The problem still exist

Comment: First, try cleaning the project and see if the errors go away. Secondly, if that doesn't work, look in the 'problems' view and see what kind of error message it is (should say on the right something like "Java Problem" or "HTML Problem" - that will give a clue as to which type of validator is raising the problem.

Comment: Cleaning did not help (I did it several times). The message shows "PHP Syntax Error". And mostly "<%" , "<%=" , "%>" tags are highlited. Therefore I turned on "Use short tags" option, which did not work.

Comment: Ah, so it's not a validation error then :) Looking at the PHP preferences, the short tags are using the <? tag elements: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.php.help/html/reference/preferences/php_interpreter.html?cp=61_4_3_8 rather than <% which is presumably the Cakewalk reference. Are these in PHP files?

Comment: .ctp files actualy (but I added this extention)

Comment: [**Bake**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake.html) templates (which is what you are looking at) simply aren't valid PHP, even if the parser understands the [**ASP-style tags**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags), the tags are nested, and therefore it's invalid syntax. The ASP style tags are used as placeholders for actual PHP tags that are being used when evaluating the template. @Annabelle